# Unable to deploy smart contract on testnet or by using testrpc stuck

Tags: solidity, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have completed writing a smart contract successfully and using Ethereum Wallet to deploy contract. After waiting for 3 days I have synced testnet Ropsten successfully but not able to mine ethers, faucets also don't work.

Another question is that when I deploy this in main network how much time does it take to to sync the main network?

Have also tried using testrpc with Ethereum Wallet but whenerver i try doing any transaction I get error "unable to estimate gas" and geth console shows gas{} null, none of the solutions on internet helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Rinkeby](http://www.rinkeby.io) testnet to deploy contract, it should work better than Ropsten because it has protection agains malicious attacks, and the faucet should work.

Synchronization to mainnet depends on your hardware and network connections. With a good connection, SSD disk, and at least 8Gb of RAM it should complete a fasty sync between several hours and one or two days. With HDD disk was almost impossible to synchronize a month ago, it might be better in recent version but I didn't test.